# Formula with sum total on Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, cell, formula

I have a formula: `|Xi-(1/n)*∑X-i|`, and I am trying to  apply it to a cell-type variable `B` with `27 rows * 10 columns` in MATLAB, where `X = B(:,10)` , `i = analyst` and `–i= all other analysts` w/ exception from analyst i.

I am having problems in applying the `sum function` and putting it together with `abs function` and `cell2mat`. This is what I have so far:

```
B(:,11)=(abs(cell2mat(B(:,10)) - cell2mat((1./size(B,1))*sum(B(:,10)))));
```

I would like to get the sum of all the rows `except` the one that corresponds to the analyst i.

Can someone help me? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `analyst?` Please make an example for the input and the desired output.

Comment: try this

 `B(:,11)=(abs(cell2mat(B(:,10)) -  (sum(cell2mat(B(:,10))) - cell2mat(B(i,10)))/size(B,1) ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
B(:,11)=num2cell(abs(cell2mat(B(:,10))-((1/size(B,1))*sum(cell2mat(B(:,10))))));
```

For example: Here `"B"` is a `27 X 10` cell array.

B =

```
[35]    [76]    [68]    [59]    [13]    [63]    [ 35]    [ 47]    [30]    [ 7]
[15]    [38]    [50]    [25]    [21]    [58]    [ 45]    [ 92]    [ 5]    [79]
[59]    [22]    [19]    [67]    [15]    [ 6]    [  6]    [ 11]    [51]    [34]
[27]    [80]    [50]    [ 9]    [19]    [94]    [ 18]    [ 75]    [77]    [61]
[ 5]    [95]    [15]    [63]    [ 5]    [73]    [ 67]    [ 74]    [64]    [75]
[76]    [33]    [ 6]    [67]    [64]    [74]    [ 34]    [ 57]    [ 9]    [11]
[25]    [68]    [86]    [73]    [29]    [ 7]    [ 90]    [ 19]    [ 9]    [13]
[45]    [44]    [57]    [90]    [54]    [87]    [ 12]    [ 60]    [78]    [55]
[69]    [84]    [93]    [99]    [70]    [94]    [ 99]    [ 30]    [91]    [49]
[36]    [77]    [70]    [77]    [50]    [99]    [ 54]    [ 14]    [54]    [90]
[74]    [17]    [59]    [59]    [54]    [86]    [ 71]    [ 22]    [11]    [80]
[40]    [87]    [82]    [93]    [45]    [79]    [100]    [ 90]    [83]    [74]
[69]    [99]    [88]    [59]    [13]    [52]    [ 29]    [  8]    [34]    [ 6]
[71]    [52]    [99]    [ 2]    [50]    [18]    [ 42]    [ 25]    [30]    [ 8]
[45]    [89]    [ 1]    [13]    [86]    [40]    [ 47]    [  6]    [75]    [ 9]
[ 2]    [59]    [87]    [87]    [88]    [14]    [ 77]    [ 45]    [ 2]    [80]
[34]    [16]    [62]    [49]    [28]    [ 4]    [ 82]    [  2]    [ 5]    [95]
[43]    [20]    [99]    [85]    [21]    [94]    [ 11]    [ 90]    [67]    [69]
[28]    [41]    [53]    [21]    [57]    [31]    [ 18]    [ 20]    [61]    [14]
[20]    [75]    [48]    [56]    [65]    [30]    [ 36]    [ 10]    [53]    [73]
[83]    [83]    [81]    [63]    [42]    [34]    [  6]    [ 31]    [73]    [12]
[43]    [79]    [23]    [ 4]    [21]    [47]    [ 53]    [ 46]    [71]    [12]
[89]    [32]    [50]    [62]    [95]    [65]    [ 34]    [ 11]    [79]    [65]
[40]    [54]    [91]    [37]    [ 9]    [ 3]    [ 18]    [100]    [29]    [33]
[77]    [ 9]    [58]    [ 5]    [11]    [85]    [ 21]    [ 34]    [70]    [66]
[40]    [12]    [85]    [49]    [15]    [56]    [ 91]    [ 30]    [56]    [75]
[81]    [14]    [74]    [20]    [17]    [86]    [ 68]    [  7]    [40]    [59]
```

**after executing the aforementioned code:**

```
    B = 

  Columns 1 through 10

    [35]    [76]    [68]    [59]    [13]    [63]    [ 35]    [ 47]    [30]    [ 7]
    [15]    [38]    [50]    [25]    [21]    [58]    [ 45]    [ 92]    [ 5]    [79]
    [59]    [22]    [19]    [67]    [15]    [ 6]    [  6]    [ 11]    [51]    [34]
    [27]    [80]    [50]    [ 9]    [19]    [94]    [ 18]    [ 75]    [77]    [61]
    [ 5]    [95]    [15]    [63]    [ 5]    [73]    [ 67]    [ 74]    [64]    [75]
    [76]    [33]    [ 6]    [67]    [64]    [74]    [ 34]    [ 57]    [ 9]    [11]
    [25]    [68]    [86]    [73]    [29]    [ 7]    [ 90]    [ 19]    [ 9]    [13]
    [45]    [44]    [57]    [90]    [54]    [87]    [ 12]    [ 60]    [78]    [55]
    [69]    [84]    [93]    [99]    [70]    [94]    [ 99]    [ 30]    [91]    [49]
    [36]    [77]    [70]    [77]    [50]    [99]    [ 54]    [ 14]    [54]    [90]
    [74]    [17]    [59]    [59]    [54]    [86]    [ 71]    [ 22]    [11]    [80]
    [40]    [87]    [82]    [93]    [45]    [79]    [100]    [ 90]    [83]    [74]
    [69]    [99]    [88]    [59]    [13]    [52]    [ 29]    [  8]    [34]    [ 6]
    [71]    [52]    [99]    [ 2]    [50]    [18]    [ 42]    [ 25]    [30]    [ 8]
    [45]    [89]    [ 1]    [13]    [86]    [40]    [ 47]    [  6]    [75]    [ 9]
    [ 2]    [59]    [87]    [87]    [88]    [14]    [ 77]    [ 45]    [ 2]    [80]
    [34]    [16]    [62]    [49]    [28]    [ 4]    [ 82]    [  2]    [ 5]    [95]
    [43]    [20]    [99]    [85]    [21]    [94]    [ 11]    [ 90]    [67]    [69]
    [28]    [41]    [53]    [21]    [57]    [31]    [ 18]    [ 20]    [61]    [14]
    [20]    [75]    [48]    [56]    [65]    [30]    [ 36]    [ 10]    [53]    [73]
    [83]    [83]    [81]    [63]    [42]    [34]    [  6]    [ 31]    [73]    [12]
    [43]    [79]    [23]    [ 4]    [21]    [47]    [ 53]    [ 46]    [71]    [12]
    [89]    [32]    [50]    [62]    [95]    [65]    [ 34]    [ 11]    [79]    [65]
    [40]    [54]    [91]    [37]    [ 9]    [ 3]    [ 18]    [100]    [29]    [33]
    [77]    [ 9]    [58]    [ 5]    [11]    [85]    [ 21]    [ 34]    [70]    [66]
    [40]    [12]    [85]    [49]    [15]    [56]    [ 91]    [ 30]    [56]    [75]
    [81]    [14]    [74]    [20]    [17]    [86]    [ 68]    [  7]    [40]    [59]

  Column 11

    [41.2963]
    [30.7037]
    [14.2963]
    [12.7037]
    [26.7037]
    [37.2963]
    [35.2963]
    [ 6.7037]
    [ 0.7037]
    [41.7037]
    [31.7037]
    [25.7037]
    [42.2963]
    [40.2963]
    [39.2963]
    [31.7037]
    [46.7037]
    [20.7037]
    [34.2963]
    [24.7037]
    [36.2963]
    [36.2963]
    [16.7037]
    [15.2963]
    [17.7037]
    [26.7037]
    [10.7037]
```

Comment: You should consider using `cell2mat` to simplify this and create a 2D matrix out of this.

Comment: @Naveen thank you. The code is works perfectly! The outcome is not 100% what I want, but I will work on that. Thank you for the hard work!